# "address access protected" error on calling member function while debugging using lldb

Tags: clang, lldb

I am trying to debug the clang executable using the LLDB debugger. I have built the LLVM and clang from source using `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` configuration. I am able to correctly set breakpoints in the code, but I am getting an error while trying to call member functions at the breakpoints.

For instance, if I type the following command at the breakpoint, here `FoundDecl` have the type `clang::NamedDecl*.

```
print FoundDecl->getIdentifier();
```

I am getting the following error:

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGSEGV: address access protected (fault address: 0x555555554000).
> The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

I am able to call the same function at breakpoint using gdb debugger.

Please guide and tell me regarding what is causing this issue and how can I resolve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The getIdentifier call is crashing.  You can investigate this further by substituting your `print` command with `expr -u 0 -- FoundDecl->getIdentifier()`.  That will leave lldb at the point where the expression crashed, which might help figure out what went wrong.